# How can I read qr code inside GDK app?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I want to read qr code from GDK app to get authorization token.

Is there any build in methods to read QR codes in GDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QR code could be obtained from bitmap using this [ZXing](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/) library

To get the bitmap [Glass camera intent](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/media-camera/camera) could be used.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
Intent objIntent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
objIntent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
startActivityForResult(objIntent, 0);
```

Comment: Were you able to read the QR code using ZXing library in Google glass?

Answer (score 0):

You can read QR using the library located at https://code.google.com/p/barcodefraglibv2/wiki/HowTo
Have tested it to work on Glass without any problem.

Comment: This is not working on the Google Glass!! You get the "Crop rectangle does not fit within image data" error. IllegalArgumentException