# How to read QR code in google glass android?

Tags: android, qr-code, google-glass, google-gdk, metaio

I am using metaio sdk for read qr and bar-code.

In Google glass i am not getting perfect result because  google glass dont have auto focus.

But google glass wifi qr code scaning is good without auto focus. I require the same functionality like wifi qr code scanning in my app. and which library use for wifi qr code scanning i am not getting.

How can i get best solution for large distance scanning qr code like wifi qr code scanning in google glass.

Comment: can you elaborate on "large distance" scanning 2-3 feet? Also is your question about scanning to input information into your app like a user or password

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can utilize utilize a version of the ZXing open source library found here https://github.com/zxing/zxing. This possibly is the same library used on the glass for 2D decoding

You can call and pass via intent to get your information in your app

```
 Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
 intent.setPackage("com.google.zxing.client.android");
 startActivityForResult(intent, QR_CODE_MODE);
```

There are two elaborated examples related to this question 
[How to scan a QR code using Google Glass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018447/how-to-scan-a-qr-code-using-google-glass/21052878#21052878)

edit: you need to download zxing's android client. You can get the latest copy that has the XE10 video scramble from their master branch.

https://github.com/zxing/zxing

Build the zxing/android package folder (eclipse/ant/android studio) and install your application)
should work as normal.

XE10 bug was fixed here: https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/39780fb86f3f887eb438edd58b323afe6142d669/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/camera/CameraConfigurationManager.java

Comment: but this not work for google glass.App is crash when use  Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
 intent.setPackage("com.google.zxing.client.android");
 startActivityForResult(intent, QR_CODE_MODE);

Comment: this solution requires that you have the zxing client application installed on the glass. Have you added it?

Comment: no i dont added this if you have then send link or code to me.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/zxing/downloads/list download "barcode scanner4.x.apk"

then if you have adb installed and glass pluggedin. adb install 'apk name'

Comment: if you run into any more issues feel free to holler. @user3437047

Comment: when i install "barcode scanner4.x.apk" and run this code "Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
 intent.setPackage("com.google.zxing.client.android");
 startActivityForResult(intent, QR_CODE_MODE);" then glass camera is different color like rainbow

Comment: its a common issue after XE10, easy fix check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19235477/google-glass-preview-image-scrambled-with-new-xe10-release

Comment: OK @Nehalkumar sorry, it looks like the 4.5x doesn't have the latest changes that has that incorporated but their master branch does.

https://github.com/zxing/zxing>

Ill also update my instructions

clone, build and install the android package and it will be fixed

Comment: error images link plese see and help me   http://i59.tinypic.com/2czawwk.jpg

     http://tinypic.com/r/2czawwk/8

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this library this may help you

https://github.com/BarcodeEye/BarcodeEye

Comment: error images link plese see and help me   http://i59.tinypic.com/2czawwk.jpg

     http://tinypic.com/r/2czawwk/8